# Why can't I replace a string with other string like this?

Tags: c, string

My code looks like this:

```
char source[] = "the wrong son";
char output[80];
int  i, j = 0;

for ( i = 0; source[i]; i++ )
    if ( i < 4 || i >= 10 )
        output[j++] = source[i];

output[j] = '\0';
```

Why can't I replace a string with other string like this:

```
source = output;
```

Instead of doing it a longer way:

```
for ( i = 0; output[i]; i++)
    source[i] = output[i];

source[i] = '\0';
```

When I tried doing `source = output;`, nothing happens.  How come?

Comment: but how you defined strings?

Comment: you can use C++ and `std::string` behave as you expected

Comment: In C string is not considered as primitive data type.

Comment: `Instead of doing it a longer way.` why go for it? have you not know [strcpy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcpy.html)?

Comment: It was an assignment of creating a removeString function (to remove a part of a string), and the book did not cover strcpy yet.  I was just wondering why `source = output` didn't do anything.

Comment: `source = output;` must produce a compiler error. Pay attention to your compiler's output.

Comment: It compiled without any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C `string` is not considered as primitive data type.hence,your statement won't fit!

Had,strings been independent and primitive data-types,you would have easily done it.But,this is restricted and against the C language specifications.

You'll have to go through the first way! Alternatively,you can also go for `strcpy()` method.

Answer (score 0):

From the C Standard ISO/IEC 9899:201x:

> An lvalue is an expression (with an object type other than void) that potentially
>   designates an object; 64) if an lvalue does not designate an object when it is evaluated, the behavior is undefined. When an object is said to have a particular type, the type is
>   specified by the lvalue used to designate the object. A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that
>   does not have array type, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-
>   qualified type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including,
>   recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const-
>   qualified type.

An array is an unmodifiable lvalue object.

Comment: Well that's bullschildt by K&R really. Of course an array name is a variable, namely an array type variable. It is just a variable that can't use it as a lvalue in an assignment, because the C language says so.

Comment: Bear in mind that K&R was written long before C standardization.  When C89 came out, K&R2 was released which had the code partially fixed up but a lot of the text remained unchanged

Comment: What did K&R mean by "arrays are not variables"?